# How to use theme function in post/page?

Tags: php, functions, pages

I want to be able to reference the theme directory in a page/post using php code. I don't know how to do this with WordPress but other CMS use something like a `path_to_home` php variable like

```
<img src="<?php path_to_home() . 'images/image.jpb'; ?>">
```

In WP I tried

```
<img class="first-slide" src="<?php get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/landing-banner.png'; ?>" alt="First slide">
```

but that doesn't work the same way or I need something different than `get_template_directory_uri()`.

BTW my output with this code is a literal

```
<img class="first-slide" src="<?php get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/landing-banner.png'; ?>" alt="First slide">
```

Comment: You are missing `echo` before calling `get_template_directory_uri()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever using any WordPress function with get_xyz_etc() make sure you ECHO the function if you want to output the value there:

```
<img class="first-slide" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/landing-banner.png'; ?>" alt="First slide">
```

It will now output the path!

Answer (score 1):

Like @czerspalace said :
you just miss `echo`

```
<img class="first-slide" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/landing-banner.png'; ?>" alt="First slide">
```